# How can I pass multiple objects back to my parent state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my react app, I have:

```
var App = React.createClass({
    getInitialState : function() {
        return {
            posts : {}  //<--- this is what I want to get data into
        }       
    },
    addPostToPosts : function(post) {
        console.log(post);

    },
```

I have another component which is basically a form, and I am able to `console.log(post)` the data it is sending back to addPostToPosts.

However, if I add another post, my post gets overwritten.  I've seen some methods where a timestamp is added.

However, is there any other way?  All I am trying to do is build up my posts with a title, message, and image URL.

Comment: You could store your posts in an array - otherwise, you would need to have some sort of unique ID for each post as a key in the posts object where the value is each post object. If order matters, then I'd still recommend an array or an ordered map.

Comment: thank you.  is there an easy way to create a key that will be a "better" solution than using timestamps?  I'm trying to search but I honestly don't know what to even search for :(

Comment: I think timestamps are a good option but you can use a uuid library - I use timestamps frequently in ordered maps so that I don't have to keep track of index order for each object in an array, I can know that order will always be the same as insertion order, and that each index will have an associative key that will allow me quick lookups for editing. To learn more about ordered maps check out the new Map spec for ES6: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map as well as immutable.js's version https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/OrderedMap

Comment: thansk a lot Sir you are helpful a lot!  one question - what happens if timestamp happens to be exact same for some reason?  does it mean the 2nd one won't work?  So if 2 posts are for some reason submitted at once at the exact same time, what will happen?  Also ES6 is new version of JS right?  Should I learn ES6 syntax first or continue with ES5 in my app and first understand the concepts ?

Comment: Correct on it being new version of JS - I'd recommend looking over some of the additions as they could always help you in your codebase or new ways of thinking (but you don't need to know new syntax to use the Map - as ES5 syntax works just fine). If timestamp is exact same for some reason, it will overwrite the existing object at that key, in which case I'd recommend going with a uuid library/function to generate unique keys if you think multiple posts could occur in the same millisecond. Or, you can concat the timestamp with some other piece of info to ensure unique.

Comment: thanks a lot again Sir.  I am going to use time stamp for now just so this app works (I am learning only) and make a note to research uuid later :)